# Laravel Model Class Cant Be Found In Routes

Tags: php, laravel

I look around about this issue but still can't understand why I'm getting error :

> Class "App\Models\MenuList" not found

`app/Models/Listing.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class MenuList
{
    public static function all()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'liston one',
        ];
    }
}
```

routes/web.php

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Models\MenuList;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('listings', [
        'heading' => 'lates listing',
        'listings'  => MenuList::all()
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Rename your file `app/Models/Listing.php` to `app/Models/MenuList.php`. Maybe run `composer dumpautoload`. Your model should also have `extends Model`

Comment: Easiest/safest way would be to use `php artisan make:model ...` when [Generating Model Classes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#generating-model-classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

create model using command

```
php artisan make:model MenuList
```

`App\Models\MenuList.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MenuList extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public static function listData()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'liston one',
        ];
    }
}
```

`routes/web.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Models\MenuList;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('listings', [
        'heading' => 'lates listing',
        'listings'  => MenuList::listData()
    ]);
});
```